# Need help with rails' basics

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello I want to make simple shopping cart. I am a beginner in programming. So please help. I have items with prices and quantities. I want to place button "Plus One", so when i press it should add one to quantity.

```
<td><%= item.name %></td>
<td><%= item.price %></td>
<td><%= item.quantity %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Show', item %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_item_path(item) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', item, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
<td><%= link_to "Plusone" %></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

Innocent suggestion. Buy a copy of [Agile Web Development with Rails 4th Ed](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails) If I remember correctly this is the same example solved there through out the book. And it worth buying.

Answer (score 1):

To be frank, this is kind of a difficult problem for a beginner. If you want a button that does nothing but add one to the quantity, you're talking about defining a custom action, so you need to read up on Rails routes. [Here's a good Railscast addressing this.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/231-routing-walkthrough) There's also a follow-up episode.

Next, if you want this to dynamically update a field on the page without reloading, you're talking about an AJAX call to your custom action. [Here's a Railscast for Rails 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery), and [here's a Railscast for Rails 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript). These should have the information you need to make an AJAX call to your controller action and handle the response, either with a success handler or a js.erb template.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the sources mentioned above, other useful sources are: [Ruby on rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/), 'Head first rails' book:)